# Creating a submit button with Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I want to create a submit button, which will return the score when clicked. However, I get the error `"getScore()` is not defined.

I also want to update the result to the *database* but not sure if I do it right.

Here's the **Javascript**

```
Meteor.user = function () {
  return Accounts.user();
};

if (Meteor.isClient) {


  Template.personality.events({
   'click :submit': function (event, template) {
     var getCheckedValue = template.find('input:radio[name]:checked');
     console.log($(getCheckedValue).val()),



     function getScore(){
        var answers = ["1","2","3","4","5"], 
        tot = answers.length;
        var score = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<tot; i++)
            if(getCheckedValue[i] ===answers[i]) { 
         score += 1; // increment only
        return score;
           }
        },              


       alert("Your score is "+getScore()+ "/"+ tot);

    // update the score to database
            var selectedUser = Session.get('this.userId');
            UserResult.update({ _id: selectedUser }, { score: 5 });
   //          }

   }
 });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template name="personality">
<h1>I see myself as someone who...</h1>

  <form>
   <ul>
    <p>...is talkative.</p>
      <li>
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q1" value = "1">1
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q1" value = "2">2
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q1" value = "3">3
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q1" value = "4">4
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q1" value = "5">5
      </li>
      <p>...Tends to find fault with others.</p>

      <li> 
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q2" value = "1">1
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q2" value = "2">2
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q2" value = "3">3
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q2" value = "4">4
        <input type = "radio" name = "Q2" value = "5">5
      </li>
         <input type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT"/>      

      </ul>
     </form>


</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
UserResult.update({ _id: selectedUser }, {**$set**:{ score: 5 }});
```

instead of

```
UserResult.update({ _id: selectedUser }, { score: 5 });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it would be great if you also take a look at the getScore() function

Answer (score 0):

I found no one answered this question, so I used the autoform package. Make life much easier.

http://autoform.meteorapp.com/quickform